# Passing an array between classes - strange error?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

So I am creating and populating an array in Class A - then in Class B I call a method of class A to get the array

**ClassA.h**

```
-(NSMutableArray*)getArray
```

**ClassA.m**

```
-(NSMutableArray* )getFeedsArray
{
    NSMutableArray *myArray;
    if (!myArray)
        {
        myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [myArray addObject: @"hello"];
        }


    NSLog (@"Feeds array: %d", [myArray count ]);

    return myArray;

}
```

}

Then in Class B - I do this:

**ClassB.m**

```
-(void)loadData
{

    ClassA *classA = [[ClassA alloc]init];

         NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [classA getFeedsArray];

           NSLog (@"Items in Array: %d", [mutableArray count]);
}
```

The above works perfectly - array counts show 1, which is what the test should do.

However, when I do this:

in **classA.m**

```
-(NSMutableArray* )getFeedsArray
{


    NSLog (@"Feeds array: %d", [feedsDownload count ]);

    return feedsDownload; 

}
```

The count is zero.

So I checked the feedDownload array in another method inside of ClassA.m that gets called before the getFeedsArray method does and it returns the correct value from that method.

However, when getFeedsArray is called from ClassB.m - the array count is zero. But it is only zero with the second version of the getFeedsArray code:

So if I do this and don't touch any other code:

```
-(NSMutableArray* )getFeedsArray
{
    NSMutableArray *myArray;
    if (!myArray)
        {
        myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [myArray addObject: @"hello"];
        }


    NSLog (@"Feeds array: %d", [myArray count ]);

    return myArray;

}
```

**Results**: 
Feeds array: 1 (from ClassA.m otherMethod) - otherMethod calls getFeedsArray method. 
Feeds array:1 
Items in Array: 1 (Inside ClassB.m)

If I then change the code like this:

```
-(NSMutableArray* )getFeedsArray
{
    NSLog (@"Feeds array: %d", [feedsDownload count ]);

    return feedsDownload; 

}
```

**Results**: 
Feeds array:1 (from ClassA.m otherMethod) - otherMethod calls getFeedsArray method. 
Feeds array:0
Items in Array: 0 (Inside ClassB.m)

So it seems the second call to getFeedsArray gives me a zero count of my array.

Sorry but, WTH is happening here and what am I missing??

Thanks!

Comment: simple dude...in second version of getFeedArray you are not even initializing the array nor adding anything to it..so what output do you expect in that case ?

Comment: **feedsDownload** gets null whenever You are out of the Class A. So You are calling a method from Class B at that time feedsDownload has not been initialised..

Comment: @Xman The feedsDownload array has already been initialised earlier up in the code. This is why on the first call to getFeedsArray from otherMethod I get the correct account. But when ClassB calls it, I am getting zero. I also tried re-initilizing it and that had no bearing on it. Thanks for the input

Comment: put break point there and check whethere it has data or not.

Comment: one more important is .. - be sure about ** feedsDownload** declared as Global

Comment: It has data there. But only when getFeedsArray is called from within it's class. So initialised has worked there. When called out of the class (ClassB) there is no data.

Comment: I don't think a global array would be the way to go. There would be no control over it and hard to trace. Will look into other options. Thanks!